# Dictionary suggestions in autopopup

Tags: dictionary, vim, popup, spell-checking

I use Vim for many years now but I still don't know how to type text with autopopup dictionary suggestions enabled (like in notepad++ or google android keyboard) without pushing any shortcut key.

These are my options in vimrc:

```
set completeopt=longest,menuone  
set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete
```

In short what I want is:
1) Only dictionary suggestion in autopopup while typing.
2) Only buffer words suggestion in supertab (using tab key)
   (but..without the buffer names included)

How can I obtain this?

Comment: Are you still concerned with a solution that shows pop up after 3 characters ?

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス, wow... it's working fine. That's what I wanted. However.. I noted a problem: I want to use PopUpDict() with the current active spell dictionary. If I use your `set dictionary+=/usr/share/dict/american-english` it doesn't give any suggestion. If I use only the current spell check dictionary it works well but my problem is that if the current spell check dictionary is not activated ...[please see next comment]

Comment: (I don't activate it by default, because I use different spell check dictionaries), than very strange things happens (p.e. the cursor moves backwards). 1) How can I activate PopUpDict() only if there is a spell check dictionary active? 2) Is there a way to activate/dis-activate PopUpDict() manually (using a shortcut)?

Comment: 1) You can check the same dicitionary option if it is empty or if it has a correct path with the variable `&dictionary`. 2) For activating and disactivating the function you can set a global variable that control the autocmd group.

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス, the variable `&dictionary` seems to be always empty even if my spellcheck dictionary is active. :(

Comment: Then check the settings of  spell options `spell` `spelllang` `spellfile` and the endcoding. (see also `:help spell.txt`)

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス, I cannot make it work. I do a `&spell` check and this seems to work but the mouse is moving not as I expected. All strange things are happening. Maybe it conflicts with something of supertab.

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス, it doesn't work at the start of line. It inserts all kind of numbers.

Comment: thanks for your feedbacks I will try to fix it.

Comment: I have updated my code I changed the function `PopUpDict()` it is much smoother now. wait for your feedbacks. ;)

Comment: No problems till yet. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: You are welcome. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. If you are using Linux you can set the existing english dictionary to `/usr/share/dict/american-english` or just set your own file:

```sh
    :set dictionary+=/usr/share/dict/american-english
```

and as the shortcut for dictionary completion in insert mode is <kbd>CTRL-X</kbd> <kbd>CTRL-K</kbd> you need to add these settings:

```sh
    :set noshowmode
    :set completeopt+=noinsert
    :autocmd CursorHoldI * call feedkeys("\<c-x>\<c-k>")
    :set updatetime=500
```

2. You can restrict the [Supertab](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab) plugin to popup only the buffer words by calling **`SuperTabSetDefaultCompletionType`** function (which is actually the default one):

```sh
    :call SuperTabSetDefaultCompletionType("<c-x><c-n>")
```

But you still need to press <kbd>CTRL-X</kbd>  before <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

3. Disable the NeoComplete plugin

```sh
    :NeoCompleteDisable
```

---

```
:help ins-completion
```

> ```
> (...)
>
> Completion can be done for:
>
> 1. Whole lines                                          i_CTRL-X_CTRL-L
> 2. keywords in the current file                         i_CTRL-X_CTRL-N
> 3. keywords in 'dictionary'                             i_CTRL-X_CTRL-K
> 4. keywords in 'thesaurus', thesaurus-style             i_CTRL-X_CTRL-T
> 5. keywords in the current and included files           i_CTRL-X_CTRL-I
> 6. tags                                                 i_CTRL-X_CTRL-]
> 7. file names                                           i_CTRL-X_CTRL-F
> 8. definitions or macros                                i_CTRL-X_CTRL-D
> 9. Vim command-line                                     i_CTRL-X_CTRL-V
> 10. User defined completion                             i_CTRL-X_CTRL-U
> 11. omni completion                                     i_CTRL-X_CTRL-O
> 12. Spelling suggestions                                i_CTRL-X_s
> 13. keywords in 'complete'                              i_CTRL-N
> ```

**Edit:**

This is related to comments below this answer: It is a tiny script `PopUpDict.vim` (it can be improved) that I coded which pop up automatically the matched words in dictionary after typing **3** characters and which give you the ability to pop up the matched buffer keywords after typing `ctrl-x` `tab`:  (newer version of vim >= 7.4)

```sh
set dictionary+=/usr/share/dict/american-english
set completeopt+=noinsert
set cmdheight=2
call SuperTabSetDefaultCompletionType("<c-x><c-n>")
NeoCompleteDisable

augroup Main
autocmd!
autocmd InsertCharPre * call <SID>PopUpDict()
augroup END

let s:count=0
function! s:PopUpDict()
    let AsciiCode=char2nr(v:char)
    if (AsciiCode <=# 122 && AsciiCode >=# 97) || (AsciiCode <=# 90 && AsciiCode >=# 65)  
        let s:count+=1
        if s:count >=# 3
        call feedkeys("\<c-x>\<c-k>")   
        endif
    else
        let s:count=0
    endif
endfunction
```

### [Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0U51E.gif)

[image]

Comment: Hello Meninx, thanks for replying. I updated my question. Hope it is now more clear. :)

Comment: Thanks but I still see suggestions of other buffer in my dictionary autopopup. BTW I'm using Win10.

Comment: Could you please explain more "other buffer" ?

Comment: Meninx, sorry, I mean that I still see suggestions of words from open buffers. (Your popup is starting after a pause of 0,5 seconds, but before your popup there is another popup popping up with suggestions of words from open buffers)

Comment: I think those words are related to [Neocomplete plugin](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim) you can disable it by pressing `:NeoCompleteDisable`

Comment: Thanks. What's the difference between autocomplvim plugin and your solution? I would like to know also if it is possible to activate the popup after 3 keys and if it is possible to use fuzzy search (writing something like 'stfn' to obtain selection of the word 'satisfaction' in the dictionary).

Comment: It still doesn't work well: your solution continues to open popups if I click on whatever word. I prefer to use autocomplvim plugin but I'm not enable to use it with dictionary suggestions

Comment: You need to understand the event that trigger the popup.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. Do you know how to activate the popup after typing 3 letters?

Comment: You need to code a function that check the input stream.  You can start from this [link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Wait_for_user_input_(getchar)_without_moving_cursor)