# vim spell: autoupdating suggestion-window for plain text?

Tags: vim, autosuggest, plaintext

I know great autocompletion plugins like YouCompleteMe for coding. I would like to have something similar for plain text files: A suggestion window (for the german language!) automatically popping up at the lets say 6th char in every word updating with each new character typed until it gets selected with ENTER or TAB else being dropped. 
All I could achieve with spell is some remapping of C-x C-k to faciliate the popup, I still have to discard the autoselection with C-e which is somewhat annoying to me.

So with the power of vimscript (or some already existing plugin): Can we make this happen?

Comment: Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41432390/4392605) it could help you.

Answer (score 1):

The [acp.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879) (formerly named AutoComplPop) automatically opens the completion popup as you type. With the `g:acp_completeOption` configuration, you can make it use a dictionary source.

Note that the plugin still works, but hasn't seen any maintenance in the recent past. Another alternative might be [neocomplete](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim), but it (and its related plugins like *neocomplcache*) have also seen much turmoil.

Comment: It works great for open buffer completions, unfortunately I can't find no help for the option you mentioned above. I tried to set dictionary option in vimrc to the one use with spell, but this didn't work. What do I have to set acp_completeOption to, to make it use the spell dictionary?